# How to reverse alphabetical order of string

Tags: c#

How to reverse alphabetical order of string

I would like to know how to reverse the individual characters in a string, plus numbers. I've tried it already in a very simple manner by doing the following, but for logical reasons this didn't work:

**DECODED**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

**ENCODED**

```
abcdefghijklmmlkjihgfedcba
```

I used a very simple string.Replace to get this. As you can see, only half of the string is getting reversed. I'm not sure if my logic is correct, but I think that this is because the string gets converted as a whole, rather than every character in it individually. I would like to know what the best way is to reverse alphabetical characters and numbers, so I can get a proper output. Examples are more than welcome!

Comment: show your code.

Comment: for the people answering, please read the post.  op, please clarify.  do you want to reverse the alphabetical order?  as in, a gets replaced with z, b gets replaced with y, etc.?  what about numbers?  do you want 0 to go to 9?  or do you want to reverse the order of individual characters in the string?

Comment: It's easy to see what you're doing wrong; something like 'put the first character in the last character's position _*in place*_, repeat down (and up) the line'. Instead of doing the replacement on your initial string, save the results (as you go) to a separate string and you'll probably be able to use the same logic you already have. A post of your code would still be beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;

//...

string f = "abcdefghijklmmlkjihgfedcba"
string r = new string(f.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: Downvoter, please explain.

Comment: there is no Reverse method on String. There is one on IEnumerable<char> (implemented by String), but it returns an IEnumerable<char>, not a string

Comment: -1 op wants to reverse alphabetical order of a string, not reverse the order of the characters in the string. -1 again, what @ThomasLevesque said: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @thang Yes, I appreciate Thomas's comment.  However, I do not know what "reverse the alphabetical order of a string" means, and the example in the question implies that the goal is simply to reverse the order of the characters in the string.

Comment: op specifically said "reverse alphabetical order of string".  in the example, he used string.Replace to replace a with z, b with y, etc. but what happens is that when he gets to z->a, a became z and z stayed z, so both original a and z became a.  that is why his output string looks the way it does.  This is really simple.   One way is to just convert the damn string to an array, do replacement single pass in a loop, and convert back.

Comment: +1Phoog I edited your example

Answer (score 0):

Following is one way to reverse string

```
string str= "reverse string";
string stroutput = new string(str.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```

Ext method for this

```
static class StringExt
{
    public static string ReverseStr(this string str)
    {
        return new string(str.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```

---

if want to change alphabetical order than

```
string str = "agdefbv";
char[] str = str.ToArray();
Array.Sort(str );
string s = new string(str);
```

Comment: This question is apparently the target for a swarm of drive-by downvoters

Answer (score 0):

Assuming OP wants to order alphabetically

```
string s = "yourstring";
s = new string(s.OrderBy(t => t).ToArray());
```

or

```
s = new string(s.OrderByDescending(t => t).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

*(assuming that you're trying to reverse the string, which is not very clear from your question...)*

You can use an extension method like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Reverse(this string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

        bool wasFormD = false;
        if (s.IsNormalized(NormalizationForm.FormD))
        {
            wasFormD = true;
            // Normalize to form C so that composite chars are represented as a single char
            s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
        }
        s = new String(((IEnumerable<char>)s).Reverse().ToArray());

        // Restore normalization form D
        if (wasFormD)
        {
            s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
string original = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string reversed = original.Reverse();
```

Note: the code of the extension method might seem more complex than necessary, but the normalization trick is necessary to avoid reversing the order of combining characters. Without this manipulation, a string like "Les Misérables" would be reversed to "selbaŕesiM seL" (notice the accent on the "r" instead of the "e").